# How many Geometric Progressions consisting $5$ terms are possible between $1$ to $300$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, geometric-progressions

Eg: $2,4,8,16,32.$ or $3,9,27,91,243.$
The common ratio has to be $>1$. i.e. It has to be an increasing GP.

Comment: Do you want to consider *integer* geometric progressions only?

Comment: The fun begins when the ratio is not an integer: $16,24,36,54,81$.

Comment: It definitely means integer, because there are infinitely many non-integer GPs in that range.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I suppose yeah :P

Comment: The ratio must be rational, $r = \frac{p}{q}$ with $1 \leqslant q < p$. What are the possible values of $p$?

Answer (score 2):

Let your sequence be $a,ar,ar^2,ar^3,ar^4$. You want $r$ rational,  $a$ an integer, $ar^4$ an integer, and $ar^4\leq 300$.

Now if $r=\frac{p}{q}$ is in reduced form, then $ar^4=\frac{ap^4}{q^4}$. Since $q$ and $p$ are relatively prime, this means that $q^4$ divides $a$, so you have that $ar^4=\frac{a}{q^4}p^4\geq p^4$.

So we know that $p^4<300$. That means that $p=2,3,4$. (Since $r>1$, we know that $p\neq 1$.)

This gives us a list of possible $r=\frac{p}{q}$:

$$\frac{4}{1},\frac{4}{3},\frac{3}{1},\frac{3}{2},\frac{2}{1}$$

For each of these, you need to count all $d$ such that $dp^4\leq 300$ (since then we can use $a=dq^4$.)

Comment: It might be worth recording a general formula for the number of APs, with $300$ replaced by $N$:  $$\sum_{p=2}^\infty\phi(p)\left\lfloor N\over p^4\right\rfloor$$ (The sum is finite since all terms with $p^4\gt N$ are $0$.)

Comment: But what will be the final answer? I couldn't figure it out...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Everything that people on this page suggested. I don't know how to move forward. How can I get a nice numerical number as the answer without any variables in it?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The first term of a geometric series are given as
$$a,ar,ar^2,ar^3,ar^4,ar^5.$$
and the list of above numbers is increasing (even if $r=1$), so all boils down to finding all solutions of 
$$ar^5\leq 300.$$
Start by considering for which $r$ it can hold, then focus on $a$.

Comment: That's six terms. You want to end at $ar^4$. Also, nothing says that $r$ has to be an integer.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Precisely.